# Using Declarative Client Exceptions always throws 500 from Controller

Tags: micronaut

I've got a declarative client interface and I am using it from a controller. I fully expect authentication with my service to fail right now, but I'm curious why I can't manage that exception...

```
@Controller("/order-gateway/orders")
public class OrderController {
    private final OrderClient client;

    public OrderController(OrderClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Post
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Single<String> createOrder() {
        return client.createOrder();
    }
}
```

All of the above is just sample code but when the client calls the service endpoint, it isn't authorized and returns a 401. But my controller above is returning a 500 because `client.createOrder()` is throwing an exception from getting the 401.

I kind of expected to be able to handle that but I have tried `doOnErrors` and other methods that don't seem to prevent the 500. If anything, I'd want to bubble up the 401 or at the very least, handle the 500 more gracefully. But I don't even know how to get the status code of the service call out of the async response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So something like this is likely what you're looking for:

```
    @Post
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    Single<MutableHttpResponse<String>> createOrder() {
        return client.createOrder()
                .map(HttpResponse::ok)
                .onErrorReturn(t -> {
                    HttpClientResponseException exception = (HttpClientResponseException) t;
                    return HttpResponse.status(exception.getStatus());
                });
    }
```

In order to propagate the response status you have to return an http response instead of just the body publisher. That then requires you to map the client call to a response in the success case. In the example above I also am using `onErrorReturn` to return a response in the case of an error.

Comment: Awesome. Okay, I tried getting to that; I assumed this was the solution. Thanks! I'll give it a shot in a bit and report back.

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks again.